# Error running AdMob Application: "Unfortunately Ads6 has stopped"

Tags: android, admob

I'm developing an **AdMob** app using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 7.

When I run this application on emulator and mobile it says:

> Unfortunately Ads6 app has stopped

Why does this happen?

Here is my `MainActivity` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/7xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        AdView madview=(AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adrequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        madview.loadAd(adrequest);
    }
}
```

And here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.alpha.ads6.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alpha.ads6">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>      
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>      

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ads6 is my app name

Comment: I have also added code in mainactivity as package com.example.alpha.ads6;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

Comment: Where is the backtrace to the error?

Comment: Acctually I am new to stackoverflow so unable to post question because of stackoverflow's system that marks code as not well formed

Comment: try just this, why are you referencing to class when finding a view...
 AdView madview=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

Comment: I have done like this way AdView madview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView); but still problem is not solved

Comment: @user3543644 please post logcat.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.alpha.ads6.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Use `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of       `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Comment out `MobileAds.initialize();`

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my project and it is working fine. I hope it will be helpful for you.

**Activity Code**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String ADMOB_APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-###################~##########";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,ADMOB_APP_ID);

    AdView mAdView1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest1);

}
```

**Activity XML Code**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**String XML Code**

```
<resources>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_1">ca-app-pub-################/########</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Actually adding android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"  helped me.Thanks.... Singh